# GraphQL mutation fails when passing a variable

Tags: graphql

I'm trying to send a mutation to the backend. If I hardcode all variables it's ok, but when I'm trying to pass down some values I'm getting errors

```
mutation MUTATE_AddEquipment($state: Boolean!){
    addEquipment(
      equipment: {
        id: "asd"
        equipmentId: 1
        state: $state
      }
    )
}
```

I see in the network tab that it's

```
operationName
: 
"MUTATE_AddEquipment"
query
: 
"mutation MUTATE_AddEquipment($state: Boolean!) {\n  addEquipment(equipment: {id: \"asd\", equipmentId: 1, state: $state})\n}"
variables
: 
{}
```

I also tried to pass

```
{id: "asd", state: true}
```

but it's the same result

Schema Definition:
input EquipmentMutationDTOInput {
id: String!
equipmentId: Int!
state: Boolean!
}

[image]
[image]

Comment: got it 
mutation MUTATE_AddEquipment($id: String!, $equipmentId: Int!, $state: Boolean!){
    addEquipment(
      equipment: {
        id: $id
        equipmentId: $equipmentId
        state: $state
      }
    )
}
 passing down this worked 

{"id": "asd", "state": true, "equipmentId": 10}

Comment: `but when I'm trying to pass down some values I'm getting errors` >
What are the errors you get?

Comment: in the above comment, I posted the fix for my problem. 
The errors where 404 and 500